# Python; Matplotlib: Set boundaries of Bins to integer values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I m drawing a histogram with matplot and I m wondering whether it is possible to set set boundaries of each bin to an integer value. Because if I interpret the Output values of my Plotting correctly it looks like that it is using floats. 
Input:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
(n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(counts.store_id.values, bins=10, rwidth=0.8)
```

Output for bins:

```
[   1.    66.2  131.4  196.6  261.8  327.   392.2  457.4  522.6  587.8 653. ]
```

Anyone has an idea? And is it possible to set the boundaries manually?

Thx!

Comment: If you look at the parameter description for [``bins``](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) you might find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass explicit bin edges to the `plt.hist` function. For example,

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 700, 15)
plt.hist(counts.store_id.values, bins=bins)
```

In general, the number of bins will be equal to `len(bins) - 1`. In this example, bins will be equally spaced starting with the first bin from 0 to 50 and the last bin from 650 to 700.

Comment: wouldn't `np.arange(0,750,50)` be clearer way of using `arange`?

Comment: Or `np.linspace(0,700,15)`?

Comment: I don't think you updated it in the right way though... it should be `np.arange(0,750,50)` or `np.linspace(0,700,15)`. I took the liberty of correcting it for you :)